# Can someone suggest a site which shows today's macro web traffic

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, analytics

I want to compare today's traffic for my company website with today's macro web traffic. Anyone know of a site which does this?

Mostly, I want to see trends and reassure myself that my 33% drop in organic traffic today is in line with, say, a 31% percent drop in macro search traffic (and potentially rationalized as less demand because of a long weekend or some other macro distraction).

I've found a couple sites that are close, wondering if any of you have better ones:
* [Akamai Real-time Web Monitor](http://www.akamai.com/html/technology/datavix1.html)
* [Akamai Net Usage Index: Retail](http://www.akamai.com/html/technology/nui/retail/charts.html)

Even better, I would love to find a site that tracks the current volume of web searches.

Comment: Very interesting question. But remember not to develop tunnel vision when looking at your web analytics or other metrics. I.e. the type of managers who usually have really fancy real-time performance dashboards set up, and every time they see a drop in sales/traffic they demand tweaks to the site or their marketing or sales strategy. Most feel this sort of intense monitoring of performance metrics provides accountability, but a lot of times they're just overreacting to random day-to-day fluctuations while completely missing long-term trends.

Answer (score 1):

Try [google trends](http://www.google.com/trends/) for web searches. For traffic you can try [quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/) and [alexa](http://www.alexa.com/).